# Creating Partial View to Create new in Index page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a normal index page where the list of the contents in the database are displayed. I have a create button in my Index which as of now redirects to another page to Create a new item.

First I tried partial Views to get it working but the page still redirected to another page with no layout. Then I tried using Jquery to hide/show div that contains the HTML code for Create. But I could not post the value to the correct Action method.

I am not having all that I have tried so far. I suppose my Index View wouldn't be of great interest.

**Index View when using Jquery**

```
<div> Displaying the index View</div>
<div id="Create" style="display:none">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.FamilyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.FamilyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.FamilyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.DescriptionEN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.DescriptionEN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.DescriptionEN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.DescriptionDE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.DescriptionDE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LsystemFamily.DescriptionDE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

   <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#Create').toggle();

    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller (when returning Partial View)**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
        return View("_Create");
}
```

**Index View when returning Partial View**

```
<div>
   Index View
   @Html.ActionLink("Create","Create","Controller");
</div>
@Html.Partial("_Create")
```

In none of the cases I had my `Create` displaying the way I wanted.

Based on the Answers I have tried to add the partial View and then toggle the div. but i get the following error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is
>   of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TEDALS_Ver01.Models.LsystemFamily]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'TEDALS_Ver01.Models.LsystemFamily'.

**Update : Index View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
<p>
    Search @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
</p>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#Create').toggle();

    });
});
</script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Family Name
        </th>
        <th>
            System Count
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="@item.DescriptionDE" data-placement="right">
                @Html.ActionLink(item.FamilyName, "ViewSystems", "LsystemFamilies", new { id = @item.LsystemFamilyID},null)
            </td>
            <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="Number of Systems in @item.FamilyName" data-placement="right">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LsystemCount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Add System", "Create", "Lsystems", new { id = item.LsystemFamilyID }, null)|*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.LsystemFamilyID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.LsystemFamilyID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.LsystemFamilyID })|

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" value="Create">
</div>
<div id="Create" style="display:none">
@Html.Partial("_Create")
</div>

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#Create').toggle();

    });
});
</script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

UPDATE: Create Post method

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LsystemFamilyID,FamilyName,LsystemCount,DescriptionEN,DescriptionDE,CreatedOn,ModifiedOn,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy")] LsystemFamily lsystemFamily)
    {
        lsystemFamily.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        lsystemFamily.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        lsystemFamily.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        lsystemFamily.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        lsystemFamily.LsystemCount = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (db.LsystemFamily.Any(x => x.FamilyName.Equals(lsystemFamily.FamilyName)))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("FamilyName", "Family Name already Exists");
                return PartialView("_Create",lsystemFamily);
            }

            db.LsystemFamily.Add(lsystemFamily);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView("_Create",lsystemFamily);
    }
```

Comment: The model in the `Index` view is `IEnumerable<LsystemFamily>`, but the model in the `Create` view is `LsystemFamily`. You need to pass the correct model to the partial - e.g.  `@Html.Partial("_Create", new LsystemFamily())`

Comment: I am unable to add the paramaeter `new LsystemFamily` as argument in `Html.Partial`

Comment: Its `new LsystemFamily()` - and this is the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object%29)

Comment: Yes. i could not add `new LsystemFamily`. My intellisense doesnt show LsystemFamily. I could add `Model.First()` instead to get it working though. But i will have all the text fields filled with the values of the Model

Comment: Use the fully qualified name - `new TEDALS_Ver01.Models.LsystemFamily()` or add a `using TEDALS_Ver01.Models;` in the view

Comment: Yes that worked. But still when there is an error in the Model during Create it doesnt add the validation message in the same page. it redirects to another page without the layout.

Comment: You have not even shown you POST method!

Comment: You have `return PartialView("_Create",lsystemFamily);` - what are you expecting? If you want to stay on the same page then using ajax to post the form.

Comment: To make myself more stupid, i should make the Create form as a Ajax form and not a Html form. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You have not explained what you want to achieve. If you want the create form to save a new item in the database and then update the table by adding a new row, then yes you need to use ajax (although not necessary the obsolete `Ajax.BeginForm()` method - you can just use the `$.ajax()` method)

Comment: `@Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace , UpdateTargetId="Create"})` I added this statement instead of the `@Html.BeginForm`

Comment: I check if the duplicate family anme exists in the Post method. So when there is an error it isnt displayed in the same page, but in a new page.

Comment: You should be using a `RemoteAttribute` so you can validate in the client before you submit. But ajax calls stay on the same page - if you want to go to a new page then don't use ajax.

Comment: I do not want to go to a new page. I want the the page to remain when there is an error. The model validation takes place in the same page itself. But when the model is returned from the Post method of Create it doesnt stay on the same page.

Comment: Then you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: I have already tried Remote validation and it was not working the right way, So i changed it server side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  When the create is successful , the index View is also rendered in the div where create is being called, resulting in the Index View to be displayed twice. I saw in SO, that I could wrap it inside a div, but still the problem prevails.

Comment: The typical number of comments on SO is about 5. This question (like all your questions) already has over 50. I'm done.

Comment: So if the answer has some issues the OP need not inform the person who is helping? Anyway thanks for this much help. Probably I can figure it out with an extensive Searching. Now none of my questions are having any comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you exactly want to do, I mean if you want to show Create from on a button click then just create a partail view with Layout = null i.e "_Create" ( no need an action for it), now just render this partial view  in the div that you are toggling:

```
<div id="Create" style="display:none">
  @Html.Partial("_Create")
</div>
```

and on the submission of create request if you want to refresh your index page then either you can user Ajax.BeginForm in _create view or you can post it by jquery ajax.

Comment: Give me a minute to try what you have told.

Comment: I have tried that. It throws an excecption telling that the the Partial View requires a different type than that of the Index. the index requires Ienumerable and Create requires the model

Comment: Why do you say that i do not need a action method for create?

Comment: Because its just a plane html view, you don't need a get action for it you only need a post action for it

Comment: OK. I have got it working with @Stephen Muecke's comment. I was missing to pass the model in the Partial View

Comment: Not completely. the Model error is not being posted in the Partial View

Comment: just to clear your concepts : Every view needs a model if you want to print the data from database or if you want to submit the data to database now in Index page you are having a list or IEnumerable as the model while Create view will need a single model class not the list... just pass the new instance of that model calss in the partial : @Html.Partial("_Create",new Test())

Comment: Yes. Thanks you. Now i need to change the Create form to Ajax to stay on the same page.

Comment: If you would add the parameter as well to your @html.Partial i could mark it as answer

Comment: Do you know what could be the parameter for AjaxOptions in `Ajax.BeginForm`

Comment: Its same as Html.beginform i.e. the action name and controller name also it takes aditon argument like UpdateTargetElementId

Comment: `@Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace , UpdateTargetId="Create"})` I have added something like this instead of `@Html.BeginForm`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93461/discussion-between-varun-vasishtha-and-vini-vasundharan).

Comment: I get some extra lines in my View. `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm { ` this is one extra line in my UI when the function is called.

Comment: Oh no. I cant continue this discussion in chat. My IP is blocked for chat websites

Comment: Arey its not a chat window, it is just sepearte commenting window on Stackoverflow, just click on it.

Comment: No. the site is blocked. I have already tried it many times before. The chat for Stack overflow doesnt work. but for other Stack exchange sites it works.

Comment: Then we can't extend the comments more

Comment: OK. But i have replied to your chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93716/discussion-between-varun-vasishtha-and-vini-vasundharan).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#Create').toggle();

        });
    });
</script>
```

You are trying to access `#btn` by ID, but you set it as class.`btn` is a class name.So JQuery can't find your button.Do like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn').click(function () {
                $('#Create').toggle();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: When i used the my Code the way I had I could get the Create page in my View, but I was not able to post the values to the Create action method to save it on the database

Comment: please give the action and controller name is begin form to post it

Comment: and just to clarify the button you are talking about that is given in the question is to save the value to the database. I also have another button that calls the Create partial View which has `id = btn`

Comment: But the error is being thrown before the Create partial View could be called

Comment: Use your code and try to explicitly add in BeginForm method the names of your Action and Controller names

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding you right. I should add the Action and controller name in BeginForm in the Partial View for create?

Comment: yes.In the first code with name "Index View when using Jquery" add Action and Controller name where you want to post

Comment: I will update the question with the View of the Index. Index also contains a BeginForm.

Comment: Add Method's and Controller's names to that action method from which View you are calling your Partial View.

Comment: I have added that. But still the Exception is thrown as both the Views need different models

Comment: can you send me your project?

Comment: no. its my company work. i am afraid i should not be sending the whole project. But if you are looking for a  better idea of what i am doing i could send you the wireframe design. you could send me your email or some means that i could contact

Comment: your seach submit button is posting???You can not have a two models in your page.You must create a ViewModel wich contains two models as it's field

Comment: You can not have two models in your page.You must create a ViewModel which contains two models as it's field.Wrap your models with new class and try like that.And give your View and Partial view that new VIewModel as Model

Comment: I have tried using ViewModels. But i had issues with posting the values back to the `Create` method

Comment: but in that case your post method works???You have to create ViewModels and try to work with it.And also add names to your submit buttons and pass as a parameter to your post method to see which submit button worked search or create

Comment: I do not remember. I tried the partial views long before. When I found no success i left it as it is. now again i thought of putting my hands on it. I think i never had post in Index back then. The search was added at a later stage.

Comment: If search post don't works too check your methods and paths

Comment: Currently i have search working. i am not able to render the create view as partial view.

Comment: i will try with ViewModels. give me 5 mins